# Error MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.6 IOS Swift

Tags: marketing-cloud

good afternoon, I am working with the latest version of marketingcloudsdk 8.0.6. I have followed the documentation correctly, however, my configuration code throws me this error and it is the one in its official documentation, someone could help me
i am working with xcode 13.3.1 swift ios

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Starting 8.X, SDK initialization should be done as

```
SFMCSdk.initializeSdk(ConfigBuilder().setPush(config: mobilePushConfiguration, onCompletion: completionHandler).build())
```

Please follow the link https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-configuresdk.html

Thanks,
Prakashini